# Why my query returns all items which have at least one parameter from the list instead of parameters which have all parametres from the list?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have Spring Boot application where I am doing filtering. User can filter ads through tags(ads-tags is many-to-many with third table). And everything is okay, but when I send list of tags  for filtering, my query is returning me a list of all ads which have AT LEAST 1 tag, instead returning only ads which have all tags from filter. If I make query with only one tag, everything is okay, but when I send a list case above is happening. This is my filter method:

```
@Override
    public List<AdsDTO> findAll(AdsSubGroup adssubgroup, Long userId, String status, String adsType, 
                                String businessType, Long adsGroupId, String region, Integer fromPrice, 
                                Integer toPrice, Boolean fixedPrice, Boolean freeDelivery, Boolean productWarranty, 
                                Boolean urgentSales, Boolean hasImage, Integer pageNumber, Integer pageSize, List<String> tags) {

     CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
     CriteriaQuery<Ads> query = builder.createQuery(Ads.class);
     Root<Ads> ads = query.from(Ads.class);
    // query.orderBy(builder.desc(ads.get("adsDate")));
     List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
     Join<Ads, JwtUser> adsUsersJoin = ads.join("users");
     Join<Ads, AdsSubGroup> adsAdsSubGroupJoin = ads.join("adssubgroup");
     Join<Ads, Tag> tagsJoin = ads.join("adsTags");
     In<String> in = builder.in(tagsJoin.get("name"));
     
        
          if (tags != null && tags.size() > 0) { 
              
              for (String tag : tags) {
                  in.value(tag);
             
              }
              predicates.add(in);
          }

          query.select(ads);
          query.distinct(true);
     query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
     if(!(pageNumber==null && pageSize==null)) {
         TypedQuery<Ads> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);
         typedQuery.setFirstResult((pageNumber-1)*pageSize);
         typedQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);
         List<Ads> adsList = typedQuery.getResultList();
         return AdsConverter.convertToAdsDTO(adsList);
     }else {
         List<Ads> adsList = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
         return AdsConverter.convertToAdsDTO(adsList);
     }
 
 }
```

How can I fix that query returns me only ads which have every tag from the list?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the approach, the query is wrong.

You should for example use a subquery to check that there are N entries for each article, where N is the number of TAGS entered.

Something like that:

```
//Subquery with count
Subquery<Long> countTagsSq = query.subquery(Long.class);
Root<Ads> rootSQ = countTagsSq.from(Ads.class);
Join<Ads,Tag> joinTagSQ = rootSQ.join("adsTags");

//We set the where condition by Ads id (I don't know what the attribute is called)
countTagsSq.where(
    cb.and(
        builder.equal(rootSQ.get("id"),ads.get("id")),
        joinTagSQ.get("name").in(tags)
    )
);
countTagsSq.select(builder.count(joinTagSQ ));

// Change your query where clause
query.where(cb.equal(countTagsSQ.getSelection(),Long.valueOf(tags.size())))
```

In this way, if Tags have a size of 10, it will return those Ads that have 10 of the tags you enter.